# Android common jar file in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app and two library modules - moduleA, moduleB.

Both of these modules are using a common jar file "xyz.jar" which is being placed in their respective libs folder.

When i am trying to build this project in Android studio i am getting following error -

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task 
 ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
 > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I have already enabled multi dex by adding following lines in build files-

```
    multiDexEnabled true

    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

Could anyone please help? Almost whole day have been gone without any solution.

build.gradle for ModuleA

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/bbdevice-android-3.4.1.jar')
}
```

build.gradle for ModuleB

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/bbdevice-android-3.4.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/bbdeviceotaapi-android-1.5.2.jar')
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "visa.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':moduleA')
    implementation project(':moduleB')
}
```

App Level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Tue Oct 16 14:44:59 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Build Error Received

```
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.bbpos.bb03z.c","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\work\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle file.

Comment: Edited with all the details.

Comment: Any solution to the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, Change the View from **Android to Project** and inside your **app >> libs**  paste your .jar files

Then right click on your .jar file and select **Add As Library**

It will sync your project and added as gradle dependency